# Failed to download RDP file for instance abc_webrole_IN_0 in cloud service testingservicecall

Tags: deployment, azure, cloud

Failed to download RDP file for instance servicecall_webrole_IN_0 in cloud service testingservicecall.

Details:

```
The supplied cscfg file can not be parsed. 
Got exception Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword.
```

more info:
*using windows azure for php mssql with zend.*

**ServiceConfiguration.cscfg**

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true"/>     
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />     
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="somename" />     
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="MIIBnQYJKoSomeStringPassucansee" />

      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="2013-12-31T23:59:59.0000000-07:00" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.Enabled" value="true" />
```

what to put in AccountEncryptedPassword ?

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="MIIBnQYJKoZIhv... " />
```

i m using eclipse editor.

Comment: you know you should **change your password** asap, and never share the `AccountEncryptedPassword` agen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to rebuild / redeploy the config file with the enable remote access option and the correct cert.  If you have manually pasted the encrypted password in, then you likely have a missing or extra character in the username or the password field.

The error is very clear - the config file can't be parsed because the password can't be decrypted.

Use the Visual Studio "Package" Wizard.  Right click the Cloud Project >> Package:

[image: Package]

Then click "Settings":

[image: Settings]

Choose the cert, enter a username, password and expiration date.  This will set the appropriate valuse in your ServiceConfiguration file.

Comment: can you please tell me what to put in AccountEncryptedPassword ? is the same what i m using while creating the certi ? or i have to descrept my self ?

Comment: are u getting my Question ?

Comment: i used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh404001.aspx for creating certificate, i dont know what to put in .RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword ?

Comment: install the cert on your local machine then follow the steps above to create one

Comment: you create an encrypted password using the dialog as described in the steps above, using the "package" wizard.  The wizard will put the value in the config file for you.

Comment: Visual Studio "Package" Wizard ? will it work for my php application packaging as well ?

Comment: The Azure documents describe in detail what you need to do - read http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/common-tasks/enable-remote-desktop/

Comment: Make sure that the certificate is installed (With the key, marked as exportable and password protected!) into "local" account and "personal" store. They will then be selectable from the list within the menu. This will auto populate you config as well as the thumbprint. Just be sure to select the same cert when setting up RDP.

Answer (score 0):

My experience, Just if it happens to someone else:

1) Account Expired so i went to Azure and modified the expiry date (CloudSvc/Remote Desktop)

2) Stopped working with the error posted in this thread.

3) In my case the problem was that the Azure Certificate for remote desktop expired, so you get new one with the same name CN.

4) So when i changed the expiration of the account, kept using the old certificate.

5) the reason it took me some time to find out, is that the Combo to select certificate has the same name twice:

[image: Screenshot of changing RDP user]

6) when i changed to the second item with the same name, it started working.

Comment: This worked for me. I also had to delete all my expired certs to get it working. SImply making sure I selected what I thought was the non-expired cert wasn't enough. I had to blast away all of the expired certs for some reason.